# Deploying .otf font family to FMX application

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm trying to implement a custom font family (multiple .otf files for different weights such as heavy, light, regular, ultralight...) for my Firemonkey application, which will be deployed for both Android and iOS.

Implementing the font family on iOS was pretty simple, all I had to do was include them in the info.plist file. When applying font to label, under Font > Family I only need to type "Font name" and it gets applied. Keep in mind that there is no actual "Font name" file, only "Font name Heavy" and other weights.

> Extra question here, how do I use font weight in FMX anyway? I didn't find any property for setting font weight.

However, when doing the same thing in Android, it's a completely different outcome. I include the fonts in deployment, and entering "Font name" doesn't apply it at all, but if I enter "Font name Ultralight" for example, then that font with that weight gets applied (while on iOS, adding " Ultralight" has no effect).
To make things worse, adding styles to font such as italic and bold do not apply on Android at all, while they do get applied on iOS.

Why are these two acting so differently, and how can one overcome the differences so they both display the same thing?

Comment: On iOS, the actual font name stored inside the file is used. On Android, it's the name of the file minus the extension. Make sure the filename matches the font name you wish to use and it'll work the same on both

Comment: @DaveNottage after going through similar questions, I came to the following conclusions:
1. Delphi FMX does not support font weights other than "Regular" and "Bold",
2. Deploying custom fonts on Android largely differs from iOS.

I'm surprised no one has tackled this problem yet, so I'll try my best to solve it and answer the question myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for custom fonts in Android on Delphi FMX has been recently implemented on Sydney 10.4 and its still rudimentary as of Alexandria 11. As you have noted you must enter the "complete" font name to make it work on Android as there is no official support for font weights yet.

However you can still achieve your desired results by editing and recompiling some source code located in the file `FMX.FontGlyphs.Android.pas` from your Delphi installation. You can do something like this:

1. Locate procedure `LoadResource` from class `TAndroidFontGlyphManager`. You can see how FMX looks for fonts taking only the Family name and the file extension.
2. Check the inner procedure `CreateTypefaceFromFamilyName` and how it determines the weight of the current font.
3. Following the logic of `CreateTypefaceFromFamilyName` add something like this just before the `FontFile` variable is initialized (don't forget to declare `FontStyle`):

```
FontStyle:='';
if not CurrentSettings.Style.Slant.IsRegular and not CurrentSettings.Style.Weight.IsRegular then
    FontStyle:=' Bold Italic'
else if not CurrentSettings.Style.Weight.IsRegular then
    FontStyle:=' Bold'
else if not CurrentSettings.Style.Slant.IsRegular then
    FontStyle:=' Italic';
```

4. Change the assignment to `FontFile` from:

```
TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, CurrentSettings.Family + '.otf');
```

to:

```
TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, CurrentSettings.Family + FontStyle + '.otf');
```

(repeat for .ttf as well)

This should add support for **Bold**, *Italic* and ***Bold Italic*** for Android. This can be further extended to support more font weights as well, just check the `TFontWeight` enum in unit `FMX.Graphics.pas`.